# How to find the wifi adapter for different languages with PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, wifi

A powershell script should enable/disable the wireless network adapter.
So i make use of the NetAdaper cmdlet.

```
Get-NetAdapter
Enable-NetAdapter -Name 'Wi-Fi'-Confirm:$false
Disable-NetAdapter -Name 'Wi-Fi'-Confirm:$false
```

Its works fine on english language systems.
On system with other languages configured it fails due to the wireless adapter does not have "Wi-Fi" as name.

Example would be german.

```
Enable-NetAdapter -Name 'WLAN'-Confirm:$false
Disable-NetAdapter -Name 'WLAN'-Confirm:$false
```

How to archive this script running on all languages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Get-NetAdapter` has a field named `InterfaceType` which contains a value based on this enum:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterfacetype?view=net-5.0

According to that documentation, type `71` is a `Wireless80211` device.

Just to show it's there:

```
[int][System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterfaceType]::Wireless80211
```

So you could do something like this:

```
Get-NetAdapter | Where-Object InterfaceType -eq 71
```

Which will return a list of all wireless adapters.